# tvservice-client error in xbmc under raspbian

Tags: raspbian, kodi

A few months back, I was running Michael Gorven's [xbmc](http://michael.gorven.za.net/raspberrypi/xbmc) version under Raspbian without any real issues.

Now, a few re-installs later, I have some issues with running xbmc. While navigating the gui, e.g. attempting to add a folder as a video source, I get the following error message in the terminal I started xbmc-standlone from:

> tvservice-client: No supported modes returned for group CEA in [vc_tv_hdmi_get_supported_modes_new] 
>   tvservice-client: No supported modes returned for group DMT in [vc_tv_hdmi_get_supported_modes_new]

xbmc is still running at this point, but is unresponsive, as is the terminal I started it from.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Have you solved this issue yet? If so, could you please create a self-answer and mark it as such. We are trying to get the Q:A ratio up and that would help us a ton. Thanks!

Comment: I'm afraid I haven't. And interest in the issue suggests that I won't any time soon.

Comment: hmm..that is strange. I'll see if I can't get some attention on this one. Just wondering, I'm sure you have, but have you googled the error? Eg. `tvservice-client: No supported modes returned for group CEA raspberry pi xbmc`? That might turn up something if you haven't already tried it. Best of Luck!

Comment: In regards to my last comment, the second result in google sounds similar to yours, dunno if it will help any: http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=30789&sid=ff0f16ee4a1c4e4f2186f87242651a8f

Comment: Thanks for chipping in! I seem to remember browsing that forum at the time; but this was a while ago now. Currently, my rpi is in storage while I move cities, so I can't really make any progress on it now anyway.